# What's the origin of the saying "estar cheio de nove horas"?

Tags: expressões-idiomáticas

exemplo: "Ela ficou cheia de nove horas e então eu desisti."
Why "nove horas"?  Why not "onze horas"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para benefício do pessoal da costa leste, aqui vai a definição de [***cheio de nove horas*** do Aulete digital](http://www.aulete.com.br/nove-horas):

> **1** Bras. Gír. Exigente quanto a detalhes a ponto de ser maçante, afetado, sensível demais a coisas sem importância, implicante etc; cheio de frescura; cheio de luxo.
>   **2** Diz-se do que é complicado, enfeitado, rebuscado; cheio de frescura; cheio de novidades: *Escreveu um texto cheio de nove-horas*.

Encontrei duas explicações para a origem. A primeira, que me parece a mais plausível, é a dada por Luís da Câmara Cascudo em *Locuções Tradicionais no Brasil* e apresentada no [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/cheio-de-nove-horas-mais-uma-vez/4801) e num [artigo da Veja](http://veja.abril.com.br/blog/sobre-palavras/consultorio/de-onde-veio-a-expressao-cheio-de-nove-horas/). Segundo Cascudo a expressão tem origem no século XIX, quando as nove da noite eram a hora do recolher obrigatório para pessoas decentes:

> Às nove horas caía o pano sobre a representação do quotidiano. Apenas os boêmios, notívagos impenitentes, teimavam em afrontar os perigos da noite, da polícia, dos ladrões e capoeiras esfaimados.

Mas já no século XVII o escritor português Francisco Manuel de Melo definira a nove horas como "a taxa de todo o cativeiro do matrimónio," ou seja, a hora a que o marido tinha impreterivelmente que estar em casa.

Uma pessoa cheia de nove horas teria assim começado por ser alguém excessivamente preocupado em respeitar este limite das nove horas:

> Criou-se no século XIX a figura sestrosa, cerimoniática, meticulosa, do "Cheio de Nove Horas", criatura infalível em citar regras, restrições, limites às alegrias dos outros, memorialista dos pecados alheios, fiel lembrete aos códigos e regulamentações, imperativas e dispensáveis, complicando as cousas simples."

A outra explicação, apresentada [neste outro artigo do Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/cheio-de-nove-horas-de-novo/4614), afirma sem citar fontes que a expressão vem de as pessoas se aperaltarem para ir ao teatro às nove hora. Num blog que não interessa, alguém diz que é para ira à missa, também às nove horas.

Comment: Acredito que essas últimas explicações sejam apenas suposições, ou melhor, opiniões.

Comment: Também me parece, como creio que deixo entender. Alguém que especulou aquilo, e depois a história começa a circular por aí. Até porque a ideia de uma pessoa ter muito cuidado em se aperaltar é apenas uma das facetas possíveis do cheio de nove horas.